# Probability that Amy the cyclist will complete her route within 30 days (or less)

Tags: probability-distributions

Amy has $30$ days of paid holiday, on which she decided to go for a bike journey in France. She chose a safe route of $2300$ kilometers.

Every morning Amy tosses a die, and if the outcome is $k$, where $k = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, she cycles $20k$ kilometers that day.

In which of the following intervals falls the probability that Amy will complete her route within $30$ days (or less): [6 marks]

i) $[0, 0.25]$
ii) $[0.25, 0.5]$
iii) $[0.5, 0.75]$
iv) $[0.75, 1]$

Late edit but I thought I'd update my final solution here and interpretation to the intervals $[0, 0.25]$  since I believe the answers are misinterpreting the question e.g. $P[\bar X<30]$, but not in the interval 22.5-30 days ($P[22.5<\bar X<30]$. I am not sure if I have interpreted these intervals correctly as well, or if they are meant to be standard deviations or something.

Solution:

1. Calculating the expected distance travel per day: $\mu = 1/6(20+40+60+80+100+120)=70km$
2. Translating this to the expected days required (not sure if this is correctly done, but I did): $2300/70 = 32.86$ days
3. Calculating the standard deviation to be $34.1$ 
   $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{(20-70)^2+(40-70)^2+(60-70)^2+(80-70)^2+(100-70)^2+(120 -70)^2}6} = 34.1$
4. Then by applying the central limit theorem, because as n reaches values greater than 30, $\bar x $ tends to the normal distribution $(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n})$ This also means new standard deviation of the sample mean, $\bar x$ is $6.24$
5. By applying the formulae $Z = \frac{\bar x - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$, and drawing the normalised curve for each interval, I attempted to calculate the area between the 4 intervals using the Z - table.

The only thing is this required a lot of work for a mere 6 marks and I am not sure if I have tackled it in the required way! This is an example question for a first year undergrad.

[image: Please see attachment for solutions to the intervals.]

Comment: You may apply the Central Limit Theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for response, I have spent some time practising a couple of central limit theorem questions online but I am still unsure how to apply it to this question!

Comment: I programmed it and the probability is ~15.57%.

Answer (score 1):

The mean number of km she does is $3.5 \cdot 20 \cdot 30=2100=\mu$  The variance on one day is $\frac{35}{12}$, so the total variance is $\frac {35 \cdot 30}{12}=\frac {175}2$.  The standard deviation is $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac {175}2}$  She needs to be $\frac {2300-2100}{\sigma}\approx 21.38$ standard deviations high.  Ain't gonna happen